# Azure DevOps Pipeline connect to VPN using command line

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, vpn, pritunl

We have CD pipelines set up in Azure to deploy to App Services and all works well but we want to add a stage to automate out Cypress test process.  The problem we have is our test environment is only accessible via VPN which is fine from local machines as we run the VPN client.

Does anyone know how to include a command within the Yaml pipeline to establish a VPN connection from the pipeline host which would allow our Cypress tests to run?  I'm assuming this would require a command line connection script.

We are using a Pritunl VPN server which accepts OpenVPN connections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This opens up a conversation around storing the secret and the infrastructure you have to allow that VPN client in. Azure pipelines can run arbitrary commands, but you'll need to inject the VPN secrets/key, which without strong security oversight you can have some major issues down the line.

I'd take a step back and revisit your options here, maybe build the test/ environment *in* azure, so you don't have to worry about this?

Comment: When you say build the test env in Azure - do you mean spin up a hosted VM to run the cypress tests?

Comment: Probably. Leveraging some configuration management to create repeatable (test) builds, and then leverage Azure Pipelines to run the creation, test, deploy.